# Getting value of last 2 bits in an unsigned char

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have an unsigned char and I need to check bits 1 and 2 to find the status. What is the best way to determine the last 2 bits?

I am attempting to perform an OR, but my results aren't correct. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Example:

```
10101000 = off
10101001 = on
10101010 = error
10101011 = n/a

if(data_byte_data[0] | 0xfe)
    //01
else if(data_byte_data[0] | 0xfd)
    //10;
else if(data_byte_data[0] | 0xfc)
    //11
else if(data_byte_data[0] | 0xff)
    //00
```

Comment: aren't you supposed to do AND to find the last 2 bits? `if ((data[0] & 0xFE) == 0xFE)

Comment: @Itsik: that'd be also wrong. But `if ((data[0] & 0x01) == 0x01)` would be ok.

Comment: @Nick: No, that would be wrong too!  It would also allow 0x03 as the two lsbs...

Comment: @Oli: yes that's wrong too :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
v = data_byte_data[0] & 0x03;
switch (v)
{
case 0: ...
case 1: ...
case 2: ...
case 3: ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
switch(data_byte_dat[0] & 3) {
    case 0: puts("off");    break;
    case 1: puts("on");     break;
    case 2: puts(""error"); break;
    case 3: puts("N/A");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(data_byte_data[0] & 0x0003)
{
  case 0: 
    // 00
    break;

  case 1:
    // 01
    break;

  case 2:
     // 10
     break;

  case 3:
     // 11
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch ( val & 3 ) {
    case 0: // 00
    case 1: // 01
    case 2: // 10
    case 3: // 11
}
```